# Problem : Coefficient for each values of a factor in linear regression

Tags: r, linear-regression

It's my first year using R with my own data and I've ran into a problem. When trying to code a mutiple linear regression, the output shows a coefficient value for every value of the factor instead of a coefficient for the factor itself.

I'm trying to determine which factor influences a TPI (topographic position index) that I've generated previously in between pH, area, deepness, DOC, P etc. for bog pools.

Here's an exemple :

Call:
lm(formula = TPI$TPI300 ~ TPI$pH, data = TPI)

Residuals:
Min     1Q Median     3Q    Max
-2.769  0.000  0.000  0.000  2.630

Coefficients:
Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)               0.04436    1.41000   0.031 0.975201
TPI$pH3.82                2.02016    1.99404   1.013 0.322545
TPI$pH3.84               -1.57258    1.99404  -0.789 0.439135
TPI$pH3.85                0.90726    1.99404   0.455 0.653789
TPI$pH3.87               -3.57661    1.99404  -1.794 0.087283 .
TPI$pH3.89                0.81048    1.99404   0.406 0.688523

Thanks a lot for your help!

P.S. Sorry if I've used wrong terms, I've learned everything in French !

Comment: First, remove `TPI$` from the model formula. You pass `TPI` already to the `data` parameter. Then: Why is pH a factor variable? Usually it should be continuous.

Comment: Yeah, that's how categorical variables are typically handled.... if it's not categorical convert it to numeric: `TPI$pH = as.numeric(as.character(TPI$pH))`.

Comment: And, as Roland says, simplify your call and output by not re-typing the name of the data: `lm(formula = TPI300 ~ pH, data = TPI)`

Comment: Thanks a lot! Sorry I'm quite new with the whole statistics world!